# What is the difference between last_modified_time and datetime_sent of a received email?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

The following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from exchangelib import ServiceAccount, Configuration, Account, DELEGATE

import os
import logging
from config import cfg
logging.basicConfig()

credentials = ServiceAccount(username=cfg['imap_user'],
                             password=cfg['imap_password'])

config = Configuration(server=cfg['imap_server'], credentials=credentials)
account = Account(primary_smtp_address=cfg['smpt_address'], config=config,
                  autodiscover=False, access_type=DELEGATE)
unread = account.inbox.filter(is_read=False)   # returns unread emails
for msg in unread:
    print("last_modified_time={}".format(msg.last_modified_time))
    print("datetime_sent     ={}".format(msg.datetime_sent))
    print("#" * 80)
```

gives me the output

```
last_modified_time=2017-08-01 09:37:56+00:00
datetime_sent     =2017-08-01 09:37:15+00:00
################################################################################
last_modified_time=2017-07-31 14:41:55+00:00
datetime_sent     =2017-07-31 14:40:34+00:00
################################################################################
```

Why is the `datetime_sent` before `last_modified_time`? Is it the time of the senders email server (hence it could be anything)? Was the email modified afterwards by the receiving server? How can received emails be modified? Are flag modifications (e.g. set to "read") also changing `last_modified_time`?

Comment: I think 'last_modified_time' field is only present if the message is an Attachment. That's basically the timestamp of the last modification of the attached file.

Comment: @aramaki Both messages are Multipart (I think), but only one has an attachment.

Comment: All the current Message timestamps are set automatically by the server, so this depends on the rules in place on said server. It's not specific to exchangelib, but rather a general EWS/Exchange question.